# Query to fetch Quick Find Columns of an entity in CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have added some Quick Find Columns in CRM. Now i would like to fetch those columns in the database. Can somebody tell me how can i do this with SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Every entity has its corresponding view and filtered view. In general only admins can access the standard views, so the recommended approach is to use the filtered views.

E.g. entity new_CustomEntity has a filtered view Filterednew_CustomEntity. From there it's common T-SQL.